# Augmented Reality in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, augmented-reality

I am a Beginner for Windows Phone 7. My project is on developing augmented reality in windows phone.Many of them suggested [GART Toolkit](http://gart.codeplex.com/). It seems to be good. But as a beginner i am not able to understand that. Are they any other SDK's or Toolkits available other than GART or any tutorial for GART Toolkit?  Any Windows Phone lovers here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

http://igrali.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/implementing-augmented-reality-using-gart/

It's about implementing GART in 6 easy steps. :)

Answer (score 3):

http://igrali.wordpress.com/2012/05/13/windows-phone-and-geo-augmented-reality-toolkit-gart/ is the second article that comes up in Bing when you search using the terms: windows phone augmented reality tutorial gart

Comment: Thanks @Rich Hopkins.. :) Can you tell me some set of tutorials for doing augmented reality applications in windows phone?

Comment: Here's another: http://kodierer.blogspot.com/2011/05/augmented-mango-slartoolkit-for-windows.html.  And another: http://innovativesingapore.com/2011/08/windows-phone-7-mango-augmented-reality-tutorial/?utm_medium=twitter&utm_source=innovativeSG (this one I can't open at work - site is blocked).  Here's a video (site also blocked from work) http://vimeo.com/27377090 .  Here's one that was done by someone who presented this very subject at a WP User Group meeting that I was at: http://wmpoweruser.com/for-developers-guide-to-building-augmented-reality-layer-like-apps-on-windows-phone-7/

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [Augmented Reality sample on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#BKMK_Sensors), described as:

> This sample uses the Motion API and the PhotoCamera class to create an Augmented Reality application that lets you pin labels to points in space as you rotate the device. For more information, see [How to: Use the Combined Motion API for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202984%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).